# Асинхронная обработка сообщений на стороне сервера

Tags: c#, асинхронность, tpl

Имеется код такого вида:

```
private static void Foo()
{
  while (condition)
  {
    NetIncomingMessage im;
    while ((im = s_server.ReadMessage()) != null)
    {
      // handle incoming message
      switch (im.MessageType)
      {
        case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.ErrorMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.WarningMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.VerboseDebugMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.StatusChanged:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
                // incoming message from a client
                string chat = "";
                switch ((PTypes.PacketTypes)im.ReadByte())
                {
                  case PTypes.PacketTypes.Sync:
                  {
                     //Some action
                     ...
                     break;
                  }
                        ...
                        ...
                 }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как разделить код, чтобы он выполнялся асинхронно.

С одной стороны, понятно, что нужно создать задачу на чтение сообщений *s_server.ReadMessage()*, чтобы весь разбор сообщений шел одновременно, но далее не совсем понятно, что делать и как поступить с циклом *while*, т.е. оставить так же, исправив лишь *s_server.ReadMessage()*, либо переписать по-другому. Ну а дальше вообще непонятно взаимодействие задачи в планировщике с последующими *switch-case*, в которых, по сути, тоже будут запускаться задачи.

Читаю на данный момент "Pro .NET 4 Parallel Programming in C#", но захотелось подкрепить теорию практикой, т.к. примеры там не самые сложные.

Comment: Мне хотя бы пинок нужен, как примерно все это сделать, или пример похожего кода, на коем я смог бы разложить все по полочкам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Async/Await**

Позволяет запустить задачу в фоновом потоке и при ее завершении запустить основной код.
Если тип NetIncomingMessage имеет метод GetAwaiter(), можно смело использовать данный прием.

```
async Task<bool> Loop() 
{
    NetIncomingMessage im = s_server.ReadMessage(); 
    if (im != Null) 
    {
      // handle incoming message
      switch (im.MessageType)
      {
        case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.ErrorMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.WarningMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.VerboseDebugMessage:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.StatusChanged:
        case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
        // incoming message from a client
        string chat = "";
        switch ((PTypes.PacketTypes)im.ReadByte())
        {
            case PTypes.PacketTypes.Sync:
            {
                //Some action
                ...
                break;
            }
                ...
                ...
        }
      }
      return true; 
    }
    await Loop(); 
}

async void Foo()
{
  while (condition)
  {
     await Loop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Я предполагал, что можно и даже нужно затащить весь цикл в один таск. Но останавливал себя из за мыслей связанных с тем что каждый такой таск будет потреблять слишком много памяти связанной с обработкой сообщения. Спасибо за ответ, сейчас все встало на свои места. 

Только вопрос, если NetIncomingMessage не будет иметь метода GetAwaiter() как нужно и можно будет поступить ?